# FakeItEasy & "params" arguments

Tags: fakeiteasy

I have a method with the following signature.

```
Foo GetFooById( int id, params string[] children )
```

This method is defined on an interface named IDal.

In my unit test I write the following:

```
IDal dal = A.Fake<IDal>();

Foo fooToReturn = new Foo();
fooToReturn.Id = 7;

A.CallTo(()=>dal.GetFooById(7, "SomeChild")).Returns(fooToReturn);
```

When the test runs, the signature isn't being matched on the second argument. I tried changing it to:

```
A.CallTo(()=>dal.GetFooById(7, new string[]{"SomeChild"})).Returns(fooToReturn);
```

But that was also unsuccessful. The only way I can get this to work is to use:

```
A.CallTo(()=>dal.GetFooById(7, A<string[]>.Ignored )).Returns(fooToReturn);
```

I'd prefer to be able to specify the value of the second argument so the unit test will break if someone changes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: I'm not sure when, but the issue has long since been resolved. FakeItEasy 2.0.0 supports the desired behaviour out of the box.**

It might be possible to special case param-arrays in the parsing of the call-specification. Please submit an issue at: https://github.com/patrik-hagne/FakeItEasy/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=open

Until then, the best workaround is this:

```
A.CallTo(() => dal.GetFooById(7, A<string[]>.That.IsSameSequenceAs("SomeChild"))).Returns(fooToReturn);
```

Comment: Outstanding. At first it still wasn't working, but when I changed it to A<string[]>.That.IsSameSequenceAs(new string[] { "SomeChild" }) it worked like a charm.

Comment: I also added an issue on github as requested.

Comment: Great, I'll try to come up with a fix of the issue.

Comment: Is the Workaround with IsSameSequenceAs still the way to go?
The other variations from the original questions and also A<string[]>.That.IsEqualTo() don't work with FakeItEasy 6.0

Comment: @AntonR, there should be no need for workaround. On FIE 7.3.1, ` A.CallTo(() => dal.GetFooById(7, "SomeChild"))` is working for me. If you continue to have a problem, perhaps submit a new question or [github issue](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/new).